# Ways or methods to recover a disk not detected on an operating system Windows 10 or Linux Debian 3.16?

Tags: data-recovery

I have a faulty SATA hard drive disk which is used a storage for all my past files and documents in the last 4-6 years.  This disk is used in conjunction with a "non-wall powered" docking station. There would be more than 500GB in used space of this 1TB disk.  A few weeks ago, this disk was automatically being recognised and shown on my laptop that has Windows 10 and on another computer machine with Debian Linux distros (3.16.0.4) as the desktop.  I can still hear the SATA disk running smoothly and there is no loud or abnormal clicking noises to suggest there is a physical hardware malfunction.

Now, this disk has stopped from being automatically recognised in the graphical desktop environment.  Even commands of fdisk or parted in Linux, or disk management in windows won't recognise this disk when plugged in.

Other USB devices were recognised by the 2 laptop machines.  The docking station board works since other SATA disks were recognised when substituted with the faulty disk.

Other than my educated guess that the physical disk is damaged with no obvious signs, is anyone able to point me to the right direction of other forensic disk tools or methods in an attempt to recognise, analyse, salvage or recover all my files from my disk?

I'm happy to learn and analyse the machine code or hexdump of the faulty disk or do a ddrescue-like run, but the first step would be to recognise the disk on another machine.  Which would be greatly appreciated if someone could give me a hint on how this could be done :-).

Thank you in advance. I hope to help someone else with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do to recover the data, if the disk itself is not
recognized as a disk by both Windows and Linux.

One operation that sometimes works is to wrap the disk up in plastic,
adding some anti-humidity material (such as rice), and putting it
in the deep-freeze for about an hour. If it works, you will have
limited time to save your data.

Otherwise, you could find a data-recuperation company and send it the
disk. These services are usually costly.